# Switching from Ubuntu 18.04 to Windows 10 on Surface Pro 2017

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, microsoft-surface-pro

I have a Surface Pro 2017 64-bit with Ubuntu 18.04. I'd like to revert back to Windows 10. I've been trying for 2 days now to switch from Ubuntu 18.04 to Windows 10 on my Surface Pro, but I haven't succeeded.

My best shot is to somehow put the .iso of Windows 10 using WoeUSB. My 8GB USB is formatted as NTFS. I used the command

```
sudo woeusb --target-filesystem NTFS --device Win10_1809Oct_v2_English_x64.iso /dev/sda
```

which returned a success, but when I reboot using the UEFI interface it keeps looping on the menu. I have reached the limit of my capabilities here. All the tutorials I come across are quite outdated.

Comment: You can’t install Windows in UEFI mode from a media NTFS partition. It needs to be FAT32.  The process has not changed.  The tutorials are accurate.

Answer (score -1):

1. Mount the Windows iso in linux, just double-click it, that should work.
2. Format the usb drive as [EDIT]FAT32[/EDIT] (to ensure it is empty).
3. Copy the files over to the USB drive, run `sync` from the command line to be sure and reboot from it when the `sync` completes.

Ensure you have the latest Windows 10 iso (1809), you will have to download many updates otherwise ...

PS: I have given-up using programs to "burn" ISOs to USB, with UEFI, just copy the files over, job done.